# option onclick alternative

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have a bit o' script that works in FF but not IE or chrome. The basic idea is that when you select one of the options from the drop down menu it will switch to another relevant option in the menu below. (it's in a paypal order form)

You can see it in action here - http://www.bizzaromatic.smappdooda.com/xtra/dvd.html

I figured out that FF will accept an onclick event in an option field but not IE or Chrome. Problem is now I can't figure out how to make the code work to select the right options. Any help would be great.

Added code

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult()
{
document.getElementById("price").selected=true;
}
function displayResult2()
{
document.getElementById("dvd").selected=true;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HGJ99G982KAEL">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Select One">Select One</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="DVD" onclick="displayResult2()">DVD $25.00 USD</option>
    <option value="DVD w/ 1 CCSB" onclick="displayResult()">DVD w/ 1 CCSB $35.00 USD</option>
    <option value="DVD w/ 2 CCSB" onclick="displayResult()">DVD w/ 2 CCSB $40.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Options">Options</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
    <option value="DVD Only" id="dvd">DVD Only</option>
    <option value="Red/Green" id="price">Red/Green</option>
    <option value="Red/Yellow">Red/Yellow </option>
    <option value="One of Each">One of Each</option>
    <option value="Surprise Me">Surprise Me!</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<br><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="http://www.bizzaromatic.smappdooda.com/xtra/images/dvd.jpg" border="0" name="submit" title="Buy the DVD"><br><font size=2>Click to order</font>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post what code specifically isn't working?

Comment: After some digging I figured out the problem but now have a new one.

Comment: If you can post the specific code that isn't working then that would help us...help you. I would suggest posting it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). You might also want to look into using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) which is a javascript library that will help you code for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Since it turns out option events don't work in anything but FF I just need a way to have different options trigger two different events from the select tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by adding an `onchange` event handler for your `<select>` element rather than a click handler for your `<option>` elements.

Change your `<select>` to:

```
<select name="os0" onchange="applyChange(this)">
  <option selected="selected" value="DVD">DVD $25.00 USD</option>
  <option value="DVD w/ 1 CCSB">DVD w/ 1 CCSB $35.00 USD</option>
  <option value="DVD w/ 2 CCSB">DVD w/ 2 CCSB $40.00 USD</option>
</select>
```

And add the following function in your `<script>` block (you can replace the functions `displayResult()` and `displayResult2()` with this single function):

```
function applyChange(obj) {
  if(obj.value == 'DVD') {
    document.getElementById("dvd").selected=true;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("price").selected=true;
  }
}
```

The above changes will make your page work as expected on all browsers (including IE7!)

Comment: That's awesome Thanx! I knew there had to be a simple solution. I just can't wrap my head around JS. There are so many damned options.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to post a minimal example that shows your issue rather than pointing to a page full of irrelevant stuff.

techfoobar has probably given you the answer you want, but for the record:

script:

```
function displayResult() {
    document.getElementById("price").selected = true;
}

function displayResult2() {
    document.getElementById("dvd").selected = true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="os0" onclick="displayResult2(01)" onclick="displayResult(02)">
```

If you want to call two different functions using an intrinsic event handler, put them both in the one attribute, do not duplicate the attribute:

```
<select … onclick="displayResult2(01); displayResult(02)">
```

Also, with a select element, you are much better to use onchange. Be beware that with IE, a user navigating using the cursor keys will dispatch an onchange event every time they press a key to navigate the options.

But there are far more serious issues:

1. `01` abd `02` will be treated as numbers 1 and 2.
2. the above parameters are ignored by the called function anyway, so what's the point?
3. both functions are called when a click event occurs, but each sets a different option to selected in the same select element, so the second one always wins (if a second is called at all and where they are set in different onclick attributes, the second one might be different in different browsers)

[...]

```
    <option value="DVD Only" id="dvd">DVD Only
    <option value="Red/Green" id="price">Red/Green
    <option value="Red/Yellow">Red/Yellow
```

Comment: I think you looked at the code when I was trying something else. I posted what I had above after I figured out this boards system. Thanks for the heads up tho'!

Comment: I think the arguments 01 and 02 wont cause invalid identifier errors, rather JS will consider them as octal 1 and 2.