# show two div using option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and also stackoverflow.

Please bare my english knowledge and javascript knowledge.

Here it goes......
I have Select option dropdown in my page. And I have divs.

below is my code this is working fine in firefox but not in ie or google chrome

```
function show_visibility(){
for(var i = 0,e = arguments.length;i < e;i++){
var myDiv = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style;
myDiv.display = 'block';
}
}

function hide_visibility(){
for(var i = 0,e = arguments.length;i < e;i++){
var myDiv = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style;
myDiv.display = 'none';
}
}
```

and this is my html code.........

```
<select style="width:205px;padding:4px;margin-left:1px;">
  <option onClick="show_visibility('foo1','foo4');hide_visibility('foo2','foo3', 'foo4','foo5','foo6','foo7') ">Program Eligibility Report</option>
  <option onClick="show_visibility('foo2','foo5');hide_visibility('foo1','foo3', 'foo4','foo6') ">Audit Report</option>
  <option onClick="show_visibility('foo3','foo6');hide_visibility('foo1','foo2', 'foo4','foo5') ">Status Change Report</option>
  <option value="option4">Family Affiliation Audit Report</option>
  <option value="option5">Marketing Category Report</option>
  <option value="option6">Pending Approval Report</option>
</select>
```

For the above code perfectly working in Firefox, but not in IE

Kindly help me here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [option onclick alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628082/option-onclick-alternative)

Comment: You should go with this option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook into the `onchange` event of the SELECT itself, and from there determine which option was selected.

```
<select onchange="selChange(this)">...
```

JS:

```
function selChange(select) {
    selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selectedValue == 'whatever') {
    ....your code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your help.  Can you provide me some example. So it will be helpful.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: hi @Diodeus

some where i am getting struggle can u explain me a bit more please

in the above code (your code) so here i need to put my function or the onClick stuff kindly bear me here

Comment: Remove your onlick. Put in the onchange from my example. In the "if" block, put your show_visibility code, one for each <option> value.